# Why does an exclamation mark before a variable return 'true' if the variable value is zero?

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax, operators

I looked a lot, but I couldn't find an answer for this especific case.

Why does this expression return `true`?

```
let variable = 0
!variable // true
```

I understand that the `!` mark checks if a value is `null` or `undefined`, but in this case `variable` is defined. This is tricking me.
Isn't `0` really considered a valid value?

Comment: ! is a boolean operator for a NOT gate.
We treat 1 as true and 0 as false. Therefore !0 == 1 == true.
Familiarize yourself with logical operators https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: Yes, it does. The point is I didn't know 0 is considered 'false'. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

! is known as the logical NOT operator. It reverses the boolean result of the operand (or condition)

0 is also considered as the boolean false, so when you use !variable you are using the logical operator and saying it to change the value of the variable to its opposite, that in boolean is true

0 == false == !1 == !true

1 == true == !0 == !false

in Javascript are considered false:
false, null, undefined, "", 0, NaN

are considered true:
true, 1, -0, "false".  <- the last one is a not empty string, so its true

```
if( false || null || undefined || "" || 0 || NaN) //never enter
if( true && 1 && -1 && "false") //enter
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: I see, now it is clear. What was tricking me is that I didn't know that 0 is considered 'false'. Thank you.

Comment: you are welcome =)
I've added some more truthy values to the example, might be useful to know =)

Answer (score 1):

To quote MDN Web docs, the Logical NOT `!`:

> Returns false if its single operand can be converted to true; otherwise, returns true

So in your case it returns true because `0` can be converted to false

You can check out this link:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators